# How to pass form value to model on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I'm working with codeigniter, I want to pass value from view to model, but it always give 0 value when i insert to table.

Below my form view

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="<?= set_value('lastname') ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="street">Address</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="address" cols="9" rows="4" name="address"><?= set_value('address') ?></textarea>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>


<?= anchor('welcome/clear_cart', 'Clear Cart', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) ?> 
<?= anchor(base_url(), 'Continue Shopping', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?> 
<?= anchor('order', 'Check Out', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

From this view i want to pass value of the form to "order" controller.

Bellow my "order" controller

```
public function index()
{
    $is_processed = $this->model_orders->process();
    if($is_processed){
        $this->cart->destroy();
        redirect('order/success');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Failed to processed your order, please try again!');
        redirect('welcome/cart');
    }
}
```

Then controller will pass value to "model_orders->process()"

Below code of model_order function process()

```
$data_delivery = array(
    'first_name' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
    'lastname_name' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
    //more
);

$this->db->insert('deliveryorder', $data_delivery);
```

So when i executed insert, the value which from view doesn't appear in model. 
first_name variable have '0' value, also another variable.

How i can get it works ? so i can get value from form view than from model i can insert to my table ?

Comment: You need either form to use GET or POST method, either AJAX call. From code you provided, I can't see those were used.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `<input>` elements to show up in `$this->input->post()` you must actually submit a form.

The view should look more like this.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?= base_url('order'); ?>">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="<?= set_value('lastname') ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="street">Address</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="address" cols="9" rows="4" name="address"><?= set_value('address') ?></textarea>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
  echo form_submit('submit', 'Check Out', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
  echo anchor('welcome/clear_cart', 'Clear Cart', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']);
  echo anchor(base_url(), 'Continue Shopping', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
  ?>     
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

as an add on to what @DFriend already said:

if you want to pass the posted values to the model you have to add them as a parameter.

---

**Model**

```
function process($data_delivery){
    $this->db->insert('deliveryorder',$data_delivery);
}
```

---

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $is_processed = $this->model_orders->process($this->input->post());
    if($is_processed){
        $this->cart->destroy();
        redirect('order/success');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Failed to processed your order, please try again!');
        redirect('welcome/cart');
    }
}
```